# UI-Router $stateProvider.decorator + Dynamic Loading Controllers using 'resolve'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am dynamically loading my controllers using the 'resolve' snippet in my app-config.js as shown below, which is working; but now, I want to use a $stateProvider.decorator, so I don't need to add the same snippet in every state.  I can't seem to get it to work.  Can someone help to point out the problem?

Here is the decorator that is not working:

```
$stateProvider

           .decorator('data', function(state, parent) {

               var stateData = parent(state);
               var data = stateData.data || {};
               console.log ("State Data = " + JSON.stringify(stateData));
               console.log ("Data = " + JSON.stringify(data));


               var controllerName = (state.name).replace("-", "/");
               console.log ("Controller Name = " + JSON.stringify(controllerName));


               state.resolve = state.resolve || {};

               state.resolve.load = ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {

                 var loadController = '/jbossews-1.0/' + controllerName+ 'Controller.js';
                 console.log ("loadController=" + loadController);

                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                 require([loadController], function () {
                   $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                     deferred.resolve();
                   });
                 });
                 return deferred.promise;
               }]; 

               return stateData;
           })
```

Here is the snippet in my app-config.js that is WORKING without the decorator:

```
.state ('login',  angularAMD.route({
              url: '/Accounts/Login',
              templateUrl: '/jbossews-1.0/Accounts/Login.html',
              resolve: {

                load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {

                    var loadController = '/jbossews-1.0/Accounts/LoginController.js';
                    console.log ("loadController=" + loadController);

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    require([loadController], function () {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        });
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
              }
            }))
```

The stateName looks like this in index.html:

```
<li ng-switch-when="true" ng-click="logout()"><a ui-sref="Accounts-Logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Logout</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working in the example AngularFire-Seed project, I saw the following comment that potentially relates to your problem.

> unfortunately, a decorator cannot be use here because they are not
>   applied until after the .config calls resolve, so they can't be used
>   during route configuration, so we have to hack it directly onto the
>   $routeProvider object

Please see [example code](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/components/security/security.js) from [angular seed project](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed). Even though you are using ui-router and the demo uses ngRoute, I believe the underlying premise will assist in your problem.